# Get current time including seconds from Sys.Date() in R

Tags: r, datetime-format

I am sure this is pretty basic, but I am not able to extract various peices of time from the system date.  Simply, I am not sure why I can not accurately extract the current minutes and seconds using %M or %S.  Any thoughts?

It currently is 12:38 pm on my machine.

```
> format(Sys.Date(), "%c")
[1] "12/16/2011 12:00:00 AM"

> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "i386-pc-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "i386"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "i386, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "2"

$minor
[1] "14.0"

$year
[1] "2011"

$month
[1] "10"

$day
[1] "31"

$`svn rev`
[1] "57496"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)"
```

Comment: It works for me `format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S")` "14:49:41"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For this, you probably want to use `Sys.time()` instead of `Sys.Date()`.

```
format(Sys.time(), "%S")
```

`Sys.Date` returns a `Date` object that's essentially a character string of a form like "YYYY-MM-DD".  It does not record hours, minutes, or seconds.

(This was slightly hidden from you in your call to `format(Sys.Date, "%S")` because that dispatched a method, `format.Date` that converts the `Date` object to a `POSIXlt` object that *does* have hours, minutes, and seconds.  In that conversion, the `Date` object is treated as if it represents a time at midnight GMT -- hence the value of "00" it always returns for its seconds element.)

Comment: Like I said, I was missing something very obvious.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, when it comes to missing 'obvious' things about date-time manipulations, you can be sure [you'll always have plenty of good company!](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx)

Comment: [Updated link to reference in comment above](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/).

Comment: not correct for 2022