# is there a way to select Shift F3 via r code

Tags: r

My computer screen locks after 10 mins (there is no way to change this as admin controls all of this). So, I want to write a looping code that selects "Shift + F3" keys to prevent this.

Is it possible to use code to select "Shift + F3" keys?

Looked in The interweb with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KeyboardSimulator/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the package example from @ekoam the library and function:

```
 library(KeyboardSimulator)
 keybd.press('Shift+F3')
```

Then an idea is to wrap `keybd.press` in a while loop: https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/while-loop/ or repeat loop https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/repeat-loop/ that is stopped by a condition of your choosing.

You can, for example, have the loop break once your clock reaches a certain time: [Get current time including seconds from Sys.Date() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538038/get-current-time-including-seconds-from-sys-date-in-r) but perhaps there is an easier way to do this.